# Proving that there exists a bijection of A with a proper subset of itself.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I simply want to know exactly how this particular function is bijective.[image]

Since they defined our function $g$, I would like to assume the set A to be written as $A=\ \left\{a_{\ 1}{,}\ a_{\ 2}{,}\ a_{\ 3}....\right\}$

so therefore from the defined function we can assume that $B=\ \left\{a_{\ 1}\right\}$, so if we $A-B$, we are left with $A - B =\ \left\{a_{\ 2}{,}\ a_{\ 3}{,}\ a_{\ 4}....\right\}$

Now if we pick $a_{\ 1}$ from set $B$ and plug it into our function g we should be getting $a_{\ 2}$

since $g\left(a_{\ n}\right)=\ a_{n+1\ }$ for $a_{n\ \ }\in \ B$
at the same time if we choose $\left\{a_{2\ }\right\}\in \ A-B$ into $g$ we would get
$a_{\ 2}$

So now $a_{\ 2}$ (in the range of the function) has two pre-image. I fail to understand how this function can be considered a bijection? (my apologies if my question is too elementary, I simply want to understand this theorem)

Comment: Have you tried playing with this proof under some concrete example? Say, taking $\Bbb Z$ as the infinite set, and the injection given by (1) to be just the identity function.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation to where your conclusions don't fit or a completion of the entire proof. The part that you printed only talks about (1) ⇒ (2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the construction.

They define $f(ℤ_+) = B$, so $B = \{f(n) \,|\, n ∈ ℤ_+ \}$. Since $f(n)$ is written as $a_n$, we have $B = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...\}$ and $A-B = \{ x ∈ A \,|\, \not \exists n ∈ ℤ_+: f(n) a_n = x \}$. So $A - B$ is everything that is left  when we take out the indexed elements.

So your first conclusion ($A = \{a_1, a_2, ... \}$) is not correct.

I don't know how you get the conclusion that $g(a_2) = a_2$. The definition of $g$ and the schematic image says $g(a_2) = a_3$ ($n = 2, n+1=3$).

The range of $g$ is $A - \{a_1\}$.

Comment: Oh, my mistake was that i considered the entirety of the codomain of the injective fuction $f$ (which is A) to be an indexed set. When in reality it's B and no this is not the entire proof, and it was only this specific part that i couldn't understand. Especially the Schematic diagram, thank you so much for clearing it up !